# wxformbuilder python generated code throws NameError

Tags: python, wxpython, wxformbuilder

Not sure if the background is relevant, but I'll include it in the eventuality

I'm moving from wxglade, so I generated a XRC from wxglade and imported in wxformbuilder

I have a grid that I subclass to add some functionality, in wxformbuilder it shows the grid correctly and the subclass propriety is also correct (mygrid.MyGrid)

but the generated code of course doesn't import mygrid as it should, so when running it it throws:

```
NameError: global name 'mygrid' is not defined
```

is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, found an ugly workaround that seems to work

basically I manually add the reference to the module global dictionay:
in the example the code is generated in the file gui.py and my class is inside the file mygrid.py

```
import mygrid
import gui
import sys
setattr(sys.modules["gui"], "mygrid", mygrid)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your workaround helped me for some months.

Until today, when I finally ignored the `header` field help, which states ***for C++ only***, and indicated in there the module name where I have my subclass. Now, the generated class properly imports my subclass definition.

The `header` field is right below the `subclass` field in the wxFormBuilder GUI. If you'd rather edit the wxFormBuilder project by hand, replace `<property name="subclass">mygrid; </property>` with `<property name="subclass">mygrid; mygrid</property>`. After regenerating, you'll have a `from mygrid import mygrid` line in gui.py.